# PHP JSON not returning value from php function

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, function

Say I have a function as following. `alert_danger` returns the error message in red box. `check_empty` checks if a value posted from form is empty or not.

```
function alert_danger($msg){
  $alert = "<div class='alert alert-danger' id='responseBox'>".$msg."</div>";
  return $alert;
}

function checkEmpty($postValue, $msg){
  if($postValue == null){
    echo alert_danger($msg);
    exit();
  }
}
```

Now when I want to return the function value using jSON it's not returning the same. The following error is occuring:

```
// It returns this
$msg = alert_danger("Ah! Hello Adventurer, and welcome to the town of Honeywood!");
echo json_encode(array('status' => $msg));

// But it does not returns this
$msg = checkEmpty($state, "Ah! Hello Adventurer, and welcome to the town of Honeywood!");
echo json_encode(array('status' => $msg));
```

What seems to be the problem here?

Here is my jQuery if needed!

```
$(".action").click(function() {
  var form = $(this).closest("form");
  var type = form.find(".type").val();
  var dataString = form.serialize();
  var btnValue = $(".action").html();
  var btnElement = $(".action");
  var url = form.attr("action");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType : "json",
    url: url,
    data: dataString,
    cache: true,
    beforeSend: function(){
      $('.message').hide();
      $(".overlay").show();
      $(".wickedpicker").hide();
      btnElement.html('Please wait...');
    },
    success: function(json){
      $('.message').html(json.status).fadeIn();
      // $('#content').html(json.result).fadeIn();
      $(".overlay").hide();
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(".message").offset().top }, "slow");
      btnElement.html(btnValue);
      if(type == 'admin'){
        if($('.message').find('#responseBox').hasClass('alert-success')){
          setTimeout(function(){
            $(".overlay").hide();
            window.location.replace("dashboard.php");
          }, 1000);
        }
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: where is `alert_danger` function? How are you calling `checkEmpty`? But the `checkEmpty` does not return any value... so assigning `$msg = checkEmpty` is meaningless

Comment: does `alert_danger` return a value?

Comment: Your function does not `return` any content. This would make `$msg` be `null`

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I have updated the question. Please check. I thought I did not need to mention `alert_danger()` function there so I didn't but since you demanded it I have updated it.

Comment: @Twisty my function does return a value. The things are working perfect when I do not use JSON. But if I use JSON then it's not returning any value.

Comment: well that does return a value but `checkValue` does not so change it so that it does return a value an dyou should be good

Comment: Perhaps like `function checkEmpty( $postValue=null, $msg=false ){
 return empty( $postValue ) ? alert_danger( $msg ) : $postValue;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

**PHP**

```
<?php
function checkEmpty($postValue, $msg){
  return $postValue == null ? array("status" => "error", "message" => "Empty Value") : array("status" => $postValue, "message" => $message);
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(checkEmpty($state, "Ah! Hello Adventurer, and welcome to the town of Honeywood!"););
?>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
function redirectTo(url, time) {
  if (!url) {
    return false;
  }
  time = time != undefined ? time : 0;
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = url;
  }, time);
}

$(".action").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("form").submit();
});

$("form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var type = $(this).find(".type").val();
  var dataString = $(this).serialize();
  var btnValue = $(".action").html();
  var btnElement = $(".action");
  var url = $(this).attr("action");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    data: dataString,
    cache: true,
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('.message').hide();
      $(".overlay").show();
      $(".wickedpicker").hide();
      btnElement.html('Please wait...');
    },
    success: function(json) {
      if (json.status == "error") {
        $(".message").html("<div class='alert alert-danger error'>" + json.message + "</div>").fadeIn();
      } else {
        $('.message').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>" + json.message + "</div>").fadeIn();
        $("html, body").animate({
          scrollTop: $(".message").offset().top
        }, "slow");
        btnElement.html(btnValue);
        if (type == 'admin') {
          if ($('.message').find('#responseBox').hasClass('alert-success')) {
            redirectTo("dashboard.php", 1000);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

> Typically, it is bad practice to use language X to generate code in language Y. Try decoupling the two languages by making data their only interface -- don't mingle the code.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126671/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-have-php-in-your-javascript

You have to be careful to not confuse `echo` and `return`, they do very different things.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Since you're passing back JSON data to the AJAX Call, I would advise wrapping your HTML inside the callback versus sending it back inside the JSON.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should take a look at your success function.  I think it normally runs before the page loads.  So, its possible none of the html your referencing in there exists yet.  So move it out to a function like this:

```
success: function(json) {
doSomething();
}

function doSomething(json){
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log('page has loaded now modify your html with jquery'+json);
    }
}
```

Comment: obviously we all use the shortcode now:  $(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});